# CLLocationCoordinate2D invalid initializer

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am using CLLocationCoordinate2D in to assign latitude and longitude like this

```
 CLLocationDegrees latitude = [somelat doubleValue];
 CLLocationDegrees longitude = [somelongi doubleValue];
 CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
```

When i run this code in iPhone simulator its not showing error but wheni run the same application in ios simulator 3.2 that is the iPad simulator its showing me an "Invalid Initializer" error.

How can i resolve this...Please anybody suggest me a solution to this problem

Thanks and regards,
Sankar Chandra Bose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`CLLocationCoordinate2DMake`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationFunctions/Reference/reference.html) is available only on iOS 4.0 and later. Do this rather,

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
coordinate.longitude = longitude;
coordinate.latitude = latitude;
```

Answer (score 1):

`CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` is available only from ios 4.0. Check the reference

> `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake`
>
> Formats a latitude and longitude value
>   into a coordinate data structure
>   format.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D
> CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(   
> CLLocationDegrees latitude,   
> CLLocationDegrees longitude)
```

> **Parameters**
>
> latitude
>
> ```
> The latitude for the new coordinate. longitude
>
> The longitude for the new coordinate.
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> A coordinate structure encompassing
>   the latitude and longitude values.
>
> **Availability**
>
> - Available in iOS 4.0 and later.